# How to recover lost NetBeans class?

Tags: java, netbeans

I was working on a project on NetBeans 12.4 and the moment i ran the code my pc got a bsod error and restarted itself, however the moment it restarted all the code in my one class was gone, is there any way to recover it? Its asking me to start from line 1, i checked the history but there was nothing as well

The .java file is still there and it shows its 16KB big but when i open it theres nothing

Comment: Check in the file system where the project was saved, maybe it's still there. Or use the search functionality of your operating system, assuming you remember the name of the file.

Comment: I have and tried opening  using notepad however it shows nothing sadly...

Comment: Oof, that's tough.  On the bright side I've learned from experience that code written a second time turns out twice as good in half the time :)  I suggest turning on Autosave:  Go to Tools | Options | Editor | Autosave to enable/configure auto-saving of files.

Comment: This is exactly why version control systems like `git` was invented.  Consider getting your own corner on for example github

Comment: If you ran the program the java file should have been compiled to a `ClassName.class` file. If you find the `ClassName.class` file in your project directory you could decompile it with a decompiler like `jd-gui`.